# How to stop the Gallery app from asking me to sign-in?

Tags: settings, gallery, cloud

I don't want my pictures to be synced with any of my accounts ever, I just want all of them to be stored on the phone without getting uploaded anywhere under any circumstances (neither I want it to download my other pictures from Picasa or anything else to my phone). I prefer to download them to my PC via cable and put them where I want to store them manually. The Gallery app, however, only offers me options to upload the pictures to Google, Facebook or Dropbox but not just to keep them locally and keeps asking me to sign-in. How do I configure it the way I want (local storage only)?

Comment: Note: if that should be impossible (I cannot tell as I'm not using that), you could simply "disable" that gallery app and use one of the [many alternatives](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/foto_galleries). I'm sure you'll find one you like :)

Comment: Thanks, @Izzy, I'l take a look on the alternatives but I have little idea of how to disable this. Perhaps I could use some hacky tool of those that let a root to uninstall system apps but I'd prefer not to remove it completely.

Comment: *Settings › Apps,* select the "All" tab, scroll to the Gallery app, tap it, tap the "Disable" button (if it's not there, you might have to tap the "Uninstall updates" button before). Same place you can re-enable it if needed.